# softlayer - performance storage list

Tags: api, storage, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

we are operating portal based on softlayer java api.
recently, we confirmed that there isn't some of performance products.

- capacity 5000GB, 6000GB.. and more

first of all, we checked api returned value.

we saw that softlayer api returned value is wrong.

we think that softlayer adds some capacity of performance and endurance storage
but yet, api dont' provide new feature.

when do softlayer apply to newest change at api ?

---

[test code ]

```
ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(username, apiKey);

Category.Service cs =  Category.service(client, 382l);
List<Item> items = cs.getAdditionalProductsForCategory();
logger.debug("size : {}", items.size());

for(Item i : items) {
    logger.debug("keyname : {}, desc : {}",i.getKeyName(), i.getDescription());
}
```

---

thank you.

Comment: Why are you using the getAdditionalProductsForCategory? the control portal uses the http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemPrices method to retrieve all the valid items for performance storage

Comment: this api is description at sldn. "Product_Package
SoftLayer_Product_Package::getItemPrices
Overview
Retrieve a collection of SoftLayer_Product_Item_Prices that are valid for this package." so i don't think to using to get the items of storage.

Comment: we checked Product_Package SoftLayer_Product_Package but api don't receive all items provided by softayer control portal. (4000_GB_PERFORMANCE_STORAGE_SPACE
250_GB_PERFORMANCE_STORAGE_SPACE
2000_GB_PERFORMANCE_STORAGE_SPACE
1000_GB_PERFORMANCE_STORAGE_SPACE
100_GB_PERFORMANCE_STORAGE_SPACE
12000_GB_PERFORMANCE_STORAGE_SPACE
8000_GB_PERFORMANCE_STORAGE_SPACE
20_GB_PERFORMANCE_STORAGE_SPACE
40_GB_PERFORMANCE_STORAGE_SPACE
80_GB_PERFORMANCE_STORAGE_SPACE
500_GB_PERFORMANCE_STORAGE_SPACE),

Comment: the getItemPrices is used in the portal because the portal needs to get the prices information for the order, but if you do not want to get the prices you can use the Product_Package SoftLayer_Product_Package::getItems , and also what package id are you using? the control portal is using the package 759 try with that package

Comment: we checked getItemPrices function and package number 759. but also this api is same.

Comment: (10 GB Storage Space
100 - 499 GBs
100 GB Storage Space
1000 - 1999 GBs
1000 GB Storage Space
10000 - 12000 GBs
150 GB Storage Space
20 - 39 GBs
20 GB Storage Space
200 GB Storage Space
2000 - 2999 GBs
2000 GB Storage Space
250 GB Storage Space
300 GB Storage Space
3000 - 3999 GBs
350 GB Storage Space
40 - 79 GBs
40 GB Storage Space
400 GB Storage Space
4000 - 7999 GBs
4000 GB Storage Space
450 GB Storage Space

Comment: 5 GB Storage Space
500 - 999 GBs
500 GB Storage Space
60 GB Storage Space
600 GB Storage Space
700 GB Storage Space
80 - 99 GBs
80 GB Storage Space
8000 - 9999 GBs)

Comment: I can see in your comments the storages listted that you want. Storage Space 4000 - 7999 , Storage Space 8000 - 9999 GBs, Storage Space 10000 - 12000 GBs, for example if you want an storage of 6000 the item for that is this " Storage Space 4000 - 7999" the description of the item is saying it an storage from 4000 to 7999 of capacity. I do not undertand why you are saying that the information is not being displayed

Comment: sorry, my comment is wrong.  i don't want  Storage Space 4000 - 7999,  8000 - 9999 GBs, 10000 - 12000 GBs, i want 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000, 11000, 12000 GB but softlayer api(getItemPrices) don't give them.

Comment: those are the items  that the API returns and  the control portal works using that data, the API does not returns the values 5000, 6000 or 7000 the control portal uses its own logic to display that information based on what the API returns.

Comment: we operate self control portal based on java api. in softlayer control portal, if its own logic uses, how can we get this item ? we don't know informations like item-id about storages.

Comment: foe example if you get this frm the API "Storage Space 4000 - 7999" you need to parse the infromation to get the range which starts from 4000 until  79999, then you can add 1000 to the initial rage (40000) unitl the end range is reached in that way you are going to get 50000 and 60000 , apply the same to the other range values and that´s it

Comment: if i add 6000 GB, what is the item id about 6000GB?

Comment: Storage Space 4000 - 7999 that one